# How can I specify the structure of a <div> conditionally in JSX?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to create a responsive `<div>` inside a React return() statement, but every way I turn, my code is errored in VSCode. One example of my numerous efforts to structure this (and the one recommended by chatGPT) is:

```
<div>
    {props.platform === "desktop" ? <div className="displaydiv"> : <div>}
    </div>
</div>
```

In this case, the first `<div>` is errored by VSCode as having no closing tag.

I'm unsure whether or not this code would actually run, ie whether the problem might just be over-enthusiastic VSCode checking. But even if this **is** the problem, this is no help to me as these errors will obscure genuine errors in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, ternary on just the opening tag won't work. You can put it on the required attribute:

```
<div className={props.platform === "desktop" ? "displaydiv" : ""}>
</div>
```

Comment: Excellent. Many thanks. I thought I'd tried this one, but obviously not. Your solution works for `style=` too. mbojko wins over chatGPT! Any idea where the rules for this are laid out?